# Tkinter root configuration

Tags: python, tkinter

For adding a title to the TKinter root, we do something like:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("<Title Text>")
root.configure(bg = "<color>")
```

My question is how do we change the font size and font color of the Title Text. Seemed to me to be a simple requirement, but other than changing the background color of root, I don't seem to be able to do anything more.

Many Thanks

Comment: the title of the root window is displayed by the window manager

Comment: There is no cross-platform way to do this, so Tkinter doesn't give you a way to do something that wouldn't work on many platforms.

Comment: If you _really_ want a custom title, you can create a window with no title bar, then add a child widget that fakes a title bar. But this will be incredibly hard to get right if you want it to look even remotely correct even for just the top 5 or so window managers (OS X, Windows, Metacity/Mutter, KWin, Enlightenment?), especially since most of them change their layout with each version and are at least partly configurable by user-selected themes…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the title font or size via tkinter. Tkinter has no control over how the window manager / os decorates the program.